# How to Update Events on FullCalendar with NgOnChanges?

Tags: javascript, angular, events, fullcalendar

I'm working on a booking room app, on Angular 7.

I'm using full calendar to show events from database.

FullCalendar is working well for one Room, but each time i switch from another room, it's initializing an other Calendar.

My code looks like this.

```js
 ngOnChanges(changes: any) {

    this.getAllReservations();
    
  }
```

```js
public getAllReservations() {

    let apiUrl: string = `api/Reservations/Room=${this.selection}`;
    this.repository.getData(apiUrl).subscribe(res => {
      this.Reservations = res as Reservation[];

      //full calendar intit
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        
        events: this.Reservations.map(function (x) { 
          return {
            title: x.Note,
            start: x.StartDate,
            end: x.EndDate
          };
        }),
      });     
      calendar.render();
      },
      (error) => {
        this.errorHandler.handleError(error);
        this.errorMessage = this.errorHandler.errorMessage;
      })
  }
```

I reapeat, this code is working well, i get my events. =>
[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz7yB.png).

But this create a new calendar below each time i call a room & that's my problem.

And I totally get it but i can't find a solution to solve my problem. 
I tried to isolate the Calendar in the ngOnInit and only update the events, but the function events does not find the Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Christophe Sacchi, if I assume you are getting reservations only for one room with your api, it's normal. You should aggregate all reservations for every rooms :

```js
public getAllReservations() {
  this.Reservations = [];
  rooms.map(room => {
    const apiUrl: string = `api/Reservations/Room=${room}`;
    const roomReservations = this.repository.getData(apiUrl).subscribe(res => res as Reservation[],
      (error) => {
        this.errorHandler.handleError(error);
        this.errorMessage = this.errorHandler.errorMessage;
      });
    this.Reservations.push(roomReservations);
  });

  //full calendar intit
  const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    events: this.Reservations.map(roomReservations => roomReservations.map(reservation => ({
        title: reservation.Note,
        start: reservation.StartDate,
        end: reservation.EndDate
      })),
    ),
  });
  calendar.render();
}
```

If you try something like that (done inline without test, so you maybe have to update it a bit), does it works ?

I'm not an Angular dev sorry.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem with this :

```js
 getAllReservations() {
    let apiUrl: string = `api/Reservations/Room=${this.selection}`;
    this.repository.getData(apiUrl).subscribe(res => {
      this.Reservations = res as Reservation[];      
    this.calendar.getEvents().map(function(x){
      x.remove();
    });     
      for (var i = 0; i < this.Reservations.length; i++){
        var x = this.Reservations[i];
        this.calendar.addEvent({
          title: x.Note,
          start: x.StartDate,
          end: x.EndDate
        });
      }    
       
    }),
      (error) => {
        this.errorHandler.handleError(error);
        this.errorMessage = this.errorHandler.errorMessage;
      }
  }
}
```

i did a loop listing all of my reservations then i added events in calendar.

Thanks anyway Leo POUPET from E-Liberty.